# How can I do to center my text using matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Hello  have this code using matplotlib :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec


Figure = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 3)
ax0 = Figure.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax = Figure.add_subplot(gs[0, 2])
ax1 = Figure.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
ax1.text(0, 0, 'Hello everybody',
     color="white", style='oblique', ha='left',   wrap=True, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center',
     bbox={'facecolor': "#34C8EC", 'boxstyle': 'round,pad=1'})
Figure.canvas.draw_idle()
plt.show()
```

I have the following problem :

I would like to center my text. How can I do this ?

[My plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK59T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec


Figure = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 3)
ax0 = Figure.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax = Figure.add_subplot(gs[0, 2])
ax1 = Figure.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
ax1.text(.5, .5, 'Hello everybody',
     color="white", style='oblique', ha='center',   va='center',
     bbox={'facecolor': "#34C8EC", 'boxstyle': 'round,pad=1'})
Figure.canvas.draw_idle()
plt.show()
```

in plt.text first x and y are the position to place the text for more reading go through the documentation https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html

output of the given code

[image: Out put of the code]